# how to use c/cpp library/functions in android

Tags: c++, android, c, java-native-interface

I want to use c/cpp functions/library in an Android application using jni.
   any suggestion / links / tutorials /example ?

my problem with pointer/structure return in c/cpp. how to use pointer/structure in android?

actually, I am trying to develop a remote desktop application through which I should be able to access my pc in android.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The Android NDK is a toolset that lets you embed components that make use of native code in your Android applications. [What is the NDK](http://developer.android.com/sdk/ndk/overview.html)

Following are some link which help you to work in Android NDK

- [Using NDK to Call C code from Android Apps](http://marakana.com/forums/android/examples/49.html)
- [Android Beginners: NDK Setup Step by Step](http://mindtherobot.com/blog/452/android-beginners-ndk-setup-step-by-step/)
- [Writing applications using the Android NDK](http://earlence.blogspot.com/2009/07/writing-applications-using-android-ndk.html)

Answer (score 5):

You need to use [Android NDK](http://developer.android.com/sdk/ndk/index.html) (Native Development Kit).

The NDK package also contains [some demos](http://developer.android.com/sdk/ndk/overview.html#samples) you can compile and run.