# How to call a C function from a react-native code?

Tags: android, c++, c, react-native, mobile

I have developed a small android application using react-native. For what it was developed, it works fine. Now to accommodate a small requirement, we need to call a library written in C. I am not sure if there will be a way to call the C code from JavaScript! But I still wanted to ask you all.

Is there a way to do this from react-native? Like I want to call some functions in the C library. If this possible, could you please suggest how? How could I start to test a very basic setup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are going to have to write some native code, search for how to call a C lib on Android, then look for react native way to link a native code with a js call.

Native Module link https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-android.html

StackOverflow question on how to run c/cpp code on android [how to use c/cpp library/functions in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4920066/how-to-use-c-cpp-library-functions-in-android?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

Comment: I am a little confused. What is the first link that you gave? It shows some Java code? Is this relevant?

Comment: React native lets you write your own native code, and then call it on your js file. You are going to have to write Java to call the C library, and create a native module based on that java, and use the first link to integrate with your js file.

Comment: This is more advanced react native code, you first gonna need to understand how React Native works, and its code flow

Comment: So you mean, react-native communicates with Java which communicates with C?

Comment: yeah, behind every js component you call, there is already a java code, react let's write you write your own native code if they don't have already implemented.

Comment: JavaScript code on react-native is just an interface to native modules, when you write a <Text/> component, it turns into a TextView on Android

Comment: Okay. It has started to make sense to me. Where shall I place the java code? Should it be inside android/app/src/main/java/com/my_app ?

Comment: Kind off, you should start following the React native Module guide, create a sample module, to see how it works, then change this module to make the C call.

Comment: this became a chat, I could explain better to you, but not here.

Comment: I cannot enter a chat room. Do not have enough repo

Comment: Ok, so look for how to write a native module, create one, make sure it works, when you understand how it works, create a new module to do what you wanted.

Comment: Any progress with the module?

Answer (score 0):

Basically it includes 3 parts.

**JavaScript to Java or Kotlin**

check out React Native's guide to [Android Native Module](https://reactnative.dev/docs/native-modules-android).

**Java or Kotlin to C**

Calling C functions from Java is enabled with a mechanism called [Java Native Interface (JNI)](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-jni) . check out [how to add C and C++ code](https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/add-native-code) here.

see more here https://thebhwgroup.com/blog/react-native-jni